# why the smallest collection of subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $closed under taking complements?

Tags: measure-theory

i have some  doubt in Borel set . [Source](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/real/notes_2016-17/real-notes-02.pdf)

My doubt  have marked in red box , given below[image]

**My attempt** : take $A=[a, b]$ ,$A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ . So $A^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

So  i think under complement it must be open but in given image it showed that under complement it is closed  so im  getting confuse

Comment: In this context, "closed under" is not referring to any sort of topological closure. It just means that for any element of this collection, the complement is also in the collection. Similarly, for the countable union/intersection, it just means that for any countable family of elementss of this collection, the union/intersection is there as well.

Comment: Please do not use images to quote text. Images are only readable by certain people on certain devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the definition of the Borel measurable sets. You start with all the open subsets, and then take all complements (adding all the closed subsets), then take arbitrary countable unions and intersections of these (getting lots and lots of new sets), take complements of these, again take countable unions and intersections of these, and so on and on and on and on. In each step you get new sets. You end up with way more than just the open subsets.